# MSDN Tuple equality C#7.3 weird line

Tags: c#, syntax, tuples, c#-7.3

I was reading about the ValueTuple on MSDN and there is one line of code I don't understand in this sample presenting C#7.3's new tuple equality :

```
var left = (a: 5, b: 10);
var right = (a: 5, b: 10);
(int a, int b)? nullableTuple = right; //this line here
Console.WriteLine(left == nullableTuple);
```

I'm used to '?' syntax like `a==b?c():d();` or `c?.ToString();` to test conditions or nullable values but this one I don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: That's not equality, it's assignment. You're declaring a variable, `nullableTuple`, and assigning it the value of the `right` tuple variable.

Comment: like `int?` which is equal to `Nullable<int>`

Comment: `(int a, int b)` is the same as `ValueTuple<int, int>` . `ValueTuple` is a `struct`. `?` makes it nullable (`Nullable<ValueTuple<int, int>>`).

Comment: `(int a, int b)` is a *type*, just the same as `int`, `string`, `System.IO.FileStream`, and so on. So `(int a, int b)?` means `Nullable<(int a, int b)>`. Since the new tuples are structs, you can declare them as nullable.

Comment: Not that the MSDN example makes sense, since in the example case right is not null and the Nullable<> feature is not used or necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(int a, int b)?` is just a tuple `(int a, int b)` which is nullable (`(int a, int b)?` or actually `Nullable<(int a, int b)>`).

Since structs (and so tuples) can't be null, you have to wrap them in a nullable to be able to make them be nullable. That is what the question mark does.

You might be used to similar cases with `int`, which can't be `null`. `int?` can.

Comment: Yes that was totally it, I just didn't see the (int a, int b) as a type thanks everyone for this !;)